# mysql query ambiguous error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the error when i am trying to query this sql.

`#1052 - Column 'charge_id' in where clause is ambiguous`

Below is my query.

```
SELECT `inmate`.`inmate_id`,`inmate`.`fname`,`inmate`.`lname`,`inmate_case`.*,`case_information`.`case_id`,`case_charge`.*,`charge`.`charge_id` FROM inmate , `charge`
LEFT JOIN `prison`.`inmate_case` ON `inmate`.`inmate_id` = `inmate_case`.`inmate_id` 
LEFT JOIN `prison`.`case_information` ON `inmate_case`.`case_id` = `case_information`.`case_id` 
LEFT JOIN `prison`.`case_charge` ON `case_information`.`case_id` = `case_charge`.`case_id` 
 WHERE(( charge_id = 3))
```

Comment: I am trying to project the First and Last name for anyones who charge_id = 3

Comment: Are you getting the error when you run the query, or when you're trying to pull the result set into an object? It sure seems likely that the case_charge table (that you're select * from) will also have a `charge_id` column.

Comment: Do not mix implicit and explicit JOIN syntax. In fact, do not use implicit syntax at all. Beyond that, just remove the ambiguity - just like you did with all the other columns. Also, don't use evil "SELECT *".

Comment: So what do i change to print this? Because i cant figure it out. Im new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have multiple tables with a column named `charge_id`.  Since you're putting it in your result set, you can change your `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE charge.charge_id = 3
```

If you only need the first and last name then you can drop some of the columns from your select - you must be pulling more than one column named `charge_id` (probably from `case_charge`).  You can simplify the SELECT to something like:

```
SELECT inmate.inmate_id, inmate.fname, inmate.lname
FROM inmate
INNER JOIN prison.inmate_case ON inmate.inmate_id = inmate_case.inmate_id 
INNER JOIN prison.case_information ON inmate_case.case_id = case_information.case_id 
INNER JOIN prison.case_charge ON case_information.case_id = case_charge.case_id
INNER JOIN charge ON case_charge.charge_id = charge.charge_id
 WHERE charge.charge_id = 3
```

and add columns to your SELECT explicitly, as needed.  I changed your `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s since you only want inmates that do appear in the `charge` table.  You would use `OUTER JOIN` if you're trying to pull inmates that MAY or MAY NOT appear in the other tables.  (Although they would still work in this case since you're putting the end field in the `WHERE` clause. Without that you would return all inmates, even if they have no cases or charges at all).

Comment: Or use an alias for the table and the field. `... FROM charge c ..... WHERE c.charge_id = 3`.

Comment: @user3398034 That applies not only to the `WHERE` clause, but also to other places where the field is mentioned (in `SELECT` in your case).

Comment: I think it's probably also in the `case_charge` table, and you're selecting * from there.